# Trouble deploying WCF Ria Services app to IIS6 - EndpointNotFoundException The service Web-AuthenticationService.svc does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We are trying to deploy a Silverlight + WCF RIA Services application to an IIS 6 web server. When the silverlight application starts in the browser I get an error. Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), I can see the real error:

> EndpointNotFoundException The service Web-AuthenticationService.svc does not exist.

Sure enough, if I try to browse to the service in a browser, it is not found:

[image]

I have researched this error as much as I could, trying these things:

- Making sure RIA Services assemblies are included in the site's bin folder.
- Then, Making sure RIA Services is installed on the server.
- Ensuring only 1 authentication scheme is being used (both in web config & in IIS site settings.)
- Triple checking that the config sections are present [as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).

Can anyone give any more advice?

## Update

I manually added the svc file to the ClientBin folder and the problem was "resolved". I'm now onto a Timeout problem when the login query is called. Why do I have to add the svc file manually?

Comment: Do any other .svc extensions work?

Comment: @rick schott - None that get generated at runtime.

Comment: just a thought, have you tried other browsers, once I had svc extensions blocked by a virus scanner in IE .

Comment: Have you registered WCF with IIS? You need to run servicemodelreg.exe found @ c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V3.0\Windows Communication Framework.

Comment: IT's 2013, and I still stuck with this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find was manually create the svc file and include it in the clientbin folder.

Comment: Even that doesn't work in my case. I used the new factory class DomainServiceHostFactory but still i get this error: The CLR Type '”System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory”' could not be loaded during service compilation

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this blog post](http://refactorthis.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/deploying-silverlight-wcf-ria-services-on-iis-6/) helpful. I've been recently dealing with WCF Ria 404 deployment hell as well - Upgrading Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 did help resolve my issues as it contains WCF Ria SP1.

Comment: did you upgrade to SP1 ? Are you sure that all required dlls are in your .Web project? Do they have the CopyLocal property set to true ?

Comment: Are you deploying your service from the .Web project? or as a WCF Ria library?

Answer (score 0):

After 7 long days we managed to find a solution i have never seen anywhere else in the forums. 
It has to do with missing datasources in the Properties folder of the silverlight project.
In my case there were no datasources generated.  (project>properties>datasources folder was empty)

The solution was to go to Data > Show Data Sources and then press the button to automatically create all datasources.

(This is on Visual studio 2010)